# Html5 Audio - Refresh Page not work to reset audio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, refresh, html5-audio

Hi I need help from you - ASP.NET MVC.

In my web application, I have a html5 audio.

It works once, but when you refresh the page, this video is in the browser's memory.

When I refresh the page, it should hit new controller action, just like the first time.

Please look at my code below:

**My View**

```
        <audio controls style="width: 400px;">
            <source src="@Url.Action("StreamUploadedSong")" type="audio/mp3" />
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
        </audio>
```

**My Controller**

```
        public FileStreamResult StreamUploadedSong()  // <--------- Do not enter here the second time.
        {
            byte[] teste = null;
            string query1 = "SELECT * FROM  Video WHERE Id= '2'";
            using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query1, connection1))
            {
                connection1.Open();
                var reader = command1.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    teste = (byte[])reader["Voice"];
                }
                connection1.Close();
            }

            long fSize = teste.Length;
            long startbyte = 0;
            long endbyte = fSize - 1;
            int statusCode = 200;
            if ((Request.Headers["Range"] != null))
            {
                //Get the actual byte range from the range header string, and set the starting byte.
                string[] range = Request.Headers["Range"].Split(new char[] { '=', '-' });
                startbyte = Convert.ToInt64(range[1]);
                if (range.Length > 2 && range[2] != "") endbyte = Convert.ToInt64(range[2]);
                //If the start byte is not equal to zero, that means the user is requesting partial content.
                if (startbyte != 0 || endbyte != fSize - 1 || range.Length > 2 && range[2] == "")
                { statusCode = 206; }//Set the status code of the response to 206 (Partial Content) and add a content range header.                                    
            }
            long desSize = endbyte - startbyte + 1;
            //Headers
            Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

            Response.ContentType = "audio/mp3";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Accept", Response.ContentType);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", desSize.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", startbyte, endbyte, fSize));
            //Data

            var stream = new MemoryStream(teste, (int)startbyte, (int)desSize);

            return new FileStreamResult(stream, Response.ContentType);
        }
```

Any idea how to refresh page to enter controller action `StreamUploadedSong` again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution !

Using Guid.NewGuid to Initializes a new instance of the Guid structure.

Bruce commented on this forum The Asp.net MVC:

**"The browser caches the audio. If you want it to fetch every time, the URL should be unique. Just add a guid to the URL."**

Source: [ASP.NET Forums](https://forums.asp.net/t/2105132.aspx?Html5%20Audio%20Refresh%20Page%20not%20work%20to%20reset%20audio%20)

Replace:

```
<source src="@Url.Action("StreamUploadedSong")" type="audio/mp3" />
```

to

```
<source src="@Url.Action("StreamUploadedSong", "Account", new {id = Guid.NewGuid()})" type="audio/mp3" />
```